# Password loop keeps repeating

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
Passlimit = 10

while Passlimit: 
   Passinput = input("how long do you want you random generate password to be? NO LONGER THAN 10 CHARACTERS:   ")
   if Passinput <= Passlimit:
       print("NUMBER SELECTED")
   else:
       print("Invalid number, NO LONGER THAN 10 CHARACTERS")
```

When i run this code the if statement works but it just repeats back to the input

Comment: You don't have a `break` - also fix your indentation.

Comment: It's not clear from your text if the user should pass a string (the password) or a number (the number of characters that the generated password should have)

Comment: You have to use **break** condition when you are using loops. In your case you have used **if...else** so it will goes in infinite asking you for input,  better is out a **break** like **exit** keyword occurred .

Comment: Can you please give the logic you are trying? how the loop should end? if `Passlimit` is the counter then add a line `Passlimit = Passlimit - 1`. If you want to break the loop if `NUMBER SELECTED` then add `break` in the if condition.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

initial value of Passlimit is 9
you have Passlimit variable referencing integer object of value 10.
while loops terminates only when expression after while keyword evaluates Fasle.
in your case

```
while Passlimit:
    #body
```

the value Passlimit is referencing is 10 which is True. all non zero integers are true in python. and the value of Passlimit is always 10 so while loops runs forever.
to terminate while loop the value of Passlimit should be equal to zero.

```
while Passlimit>0:
    # your code

    # decrement value of Passlimit
    Passlimit-=1
```

Comment: @Sanket it works for me i have attached the screenshot.

Comment: check for negative values, it will ask infinitely

Comment: thanks i got it and edited the answer. but in this context when Passlimit=0 loop will terminate and never be negative.